# How to generate and save cookies to a text file with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

So I am using Python Selenium Webdriver and my problem is that I don't know how to generate web cookies and then save/export them to a .txt file?

I tried many things but nothing worked :/

Comment: show your code trials and errors

Comment: Please do a homework. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/

Answer (score 1):

To generate a cookie in selenium, use `driver.add_cookie()`. To get all available cookies from a website, use `driver.get_cookies()`

**Final Code:** (includes saving the cookies in a txt file)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to url
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Add the cookies you want
driver.add_cookie({"name": "test1", "value": "cookie1"})
driver.add_cookie({"name": "test2", "value": "cookie2"})

# Get all available cookies
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
print(cookies)

# Open file
f = open("cookies.txt", "a")
for cookie in cookies:
    f.write(str(cookie)+"\n")
    
f.close()
```

TXT File output:

```
{'domain': 'www.example.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'test2', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'cookie2'}
{'domain': 'www.example.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'test1', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'cookie1'}
```

**Update:**

Code to read the file and get all saved cookies:

```
import json
import ast

# Open and read the file:
f = open("cookies.txt", "r")

# Remove line breaks
list = f.read().split("\n")

for cookie in list:
    print(ast.literal_eval(cookie)["value"]) # Convert output into dictionary and print cookie value

...
```